# Integrating another binary

Tags: arm, linker

I am building a binary for ARM using GCC and Crossworks. I have a secondary binary image that needs to be loaded to another IC during start up.

I like to integrate this binary to my tool-chain, in other words, I make this binary part of my image and every time I build this binary gets integrated into the final binary file that will be loaded to the CPU. What is the best practice for this?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `objcopy` to transform the binary image into an object file. The object file will contain symbols that can be accessed from C code. Then tell GCC to link the object file in and you can access the symbols in the object file using `extern` in order to load the data into the other IC.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/linking-a-binary-blob-with-gcc/) on how to link in a binary blob including how to file out the options you need to pass to `objcopy` using `objdump`.

And of course the [`objcopy` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) and the [`objdump` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump).

Comment: super answer.. it took me total of 5 mins to make this work..

Comment: Additional question. The obj file is working well however the toolchain places it in RAM which is becoming a problem due to size of the file. How can I force this object to be placed at Flash?

Comment: solved it.. basically, objcopy -I binary -O elf32-littlearm -B arm --rename-section .data=.rodata,alloc,load,readonly,data,contents fpga.bin fpga.o  this makes the whole thing .rodata and linker places correctly to the flash.

Comment: `objcopy` has a massive number of options. It can probably do anything you want. It just requires a lot of staring at that man page. Thanks for sharing your solution as I'm sure that will be a common question for people looking to do what you're doing.